# How can I insert a date that does not update, without the time, into MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-field

I need to record the date on which I have accessed a (many) URL(s) for citation purposes. I want to create a line in my Word doc that says "Accessed:" with the CreateDate field appended. I do NOT want the *time* to appear. I am using this code-

```
 Selection.TypeText Text:=" Accessed: "

Set myField = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, _
 Type:=wdFieldCreateDate)
```

It works, but I don't know how to stop the CreateDate from adding the time. I have to use CreateDate because the Date field updates every time I open the file. I have tried turning off "automatic update" in Word/Options, it doesn't work. Tried to change the default CreateDate code in the Fields/Options window, it reverts back for every new usage. I've tried a bunch of different ways, found online, to add format instructions in the macro above but none of them will run. All I want is one line that says "Accessed: yyyy-mm-dd". Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A CREATEDATE field *will not* tell you when a url was accessed; it can only tell you when a document was created or last saved via Save As. Provided you understand that:

```
With Selection
  .Text = " Accessed: "
  .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Fields.Add Range:=.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="CreateDate \@ ""D MMM YYYY""", PreserveFormatting:=False
End With
```

Change the D MMM YYYY switch to suit your requirements.

The correct way to insert the current date as a fixed string is:

```
Selection.Text = " Accessed: " & Format(Now(), "D MMM YYYY")
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Much appreciated.

Of course I know that it will not tell me when the URL was accessed. I must not have been clear. I want to *state* when I saved the URL, not *ask*. It's for my own records.

Comment: And, as I said, a CREATEDATE field cannot do that - it can only tell you when the *document* it's inserted into was created, or last saved via SaveAs.

Comment: I do understand exactly what CreateDate does. That was not the problem. Thank you.